# Get reply message from user/bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically, getting a messages from channel is done by this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == 'somechannel':
        print("AUTHOR: %s CONTENT: %s" %(message.author,message.content))
```

All plain text reply is fine and printed properly until I get a reply just like this:

[image]

I don't get anything from `message.content`. How can I get the content of a reply message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds), which will return a list of [`Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed) objects.

`Embed` has different attributes that you can check, such as `Embed.title` and `Embed.description`.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == 'somechannel':
        print("AUTHOR: %s CONTENT: %s" %(message.author,message.content))
        for embed in message.embeds:
            print(embed.title)
            print(embed.description)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are using python3.6+

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.name == 'somechannel':
        print(f"AUTHOR: {message.author} CONTENT:{message.content}")
        for embed in message.embeds:
            print(f"AUTHOR: {message.author} CONTENT: {embed.title} and {embed.description}")
```